# Reading a *.CSPROJ file in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I am attempting to write some code to read in a *.CSPROJ file using C#

The code I have is as follows

```
   XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
   xmldoc.Load(fullPathName);

   XmlNamespaceManager mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmldoc.NameTable);
   //mgr.AddNamespace("x", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003");

   foreach (XmlNode item in xmldoc.SelectNodes("//EmbeddedResource") )
   {
      string test = item.InnerText.ToString();
   }
```

using the debugger I can see that 'fullPathName" has the correct value and the xmldoc once loaded has the correct contents.

The xmldoc does not have any "Nodes" though, as if the contents are not recognised as XML.

Using a XML editor the *.csproj file validates an XML document.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Please consider changing the accepted answer for this question. Using the MSBuild API itself should be the preferred approach to manual XML handling.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You were getting close with your XmlNamespaceManager addition, but weren't using it in the SelectNodes method:

```
XmlNamespaceManager mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmldoc.NameTable);
mgr.AddNamespace("x", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003");

foreach (XmlNode item in xmldoc.SelectNodes("//x:ProjectGuid", mgr))
{
    string test = item.InnerText.ToString();
}
```

(I switched to searching for a different element as my project didn't have any embedded resources)

Answer (score 61):

Why not use the MSBuild API?

```
Project project = new Project();
project.Load(fullPathName);
var embeddedResources =
    from grp in project.ItemGroups.Cast<BuildItemGroup>()
    from item in grp.Cast<BuildItem>()
    where item.Name == "EmbeddedResource"
    select item;

foreach(BuildItem item in embeddedResources)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Include); // prints the name of the resource file
}
```

You need to reference the Microsoft.Build.Engine assembly

Comment: The Project class of Microsoft.Build.Engine is now deprecated. Any idea how to do the equivalent with the Project class from Microsoft.Build.Evaluation (assembly Microsoft.Build) ?

Comment: @ValeryLetroye, I haven't tried it, but I think something like `project.Items.Where(i => i.ItemType == "EmbeddedResource")` should work.

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for! A great way to respect all referenced  msbuild targets and their overrides! This should be the better solution from the technical perspective.

Comment: Which is the MSBuild API for UWP projects? I am not able to locate the Project in any assembly for windows 10. Is any external assembly required to be added as reference in the App?

Comment: @Tulika I'd be very surprised if it were available for UWP... You'll probably have to fall back to manipulating the XML (which, fortunately, is simple enough)

Comment: The document[https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.buildengine.project.aspx] says : 
MSBuild is now included in Visual Studio instead of the .NET Framework. You can use MSBuild 12.0 side-by-side with versions previously deployed with the .NET Framework.For more information, see What's New in MSBuild 12.0.

Still not sure how to locate it.

Comment: VS2017: `Install-Package Microsoft.Build`
and `Install-Package Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core`

Comment: It appears that Microsoft.Build.Evaluation is the correct package. See this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.evaluation?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 10):

For completeness here the XDocument version, this simplifies namespace management:

```
        XDocument xmldoc = XDocument.Load(fullPathName);
        XNamespace msbuild = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003";

        foreach (var resource in xmldoc.Descendants(msbuild + "EmbeddedResource"))
        {
            string includePath = resource.Attribute("Include").Value;
        }
```