# Updating a *.CSPROJ using MSBUILD API

Tags: c#, linq, msbuild

Based on question : [Reading a *.CSPROJ file in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649989/reading-a-csproj-file-in-c)

I have code to extract some properties out of a *.csproj file, along the lines of :

```
Project project = new Project();

var Property001=
            from pg in project.PropertyGroups.Cast<BuildPropertyGroup>()
            from item in pg.Cast<BuildProperty>()
            where item.Name == "Property001"
            select item.Value.ToString();
```

This works fine, but the next question is how do I update the property using LINQ as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use LINQ to fetch the property item - rather than just the value - to update:

```
var Property001item =
        (from pg in project.PropertyGroups.Cast<BuildPropertyGroup>()
        from item in pg.Cast<BuildProperty>()
        where item.Name == "Property001"
        select item).FirstOrDefault();
if (Property001item != null)
{
    Property001item.Value = "MyNewValue";
}
```