# UWP- Reading .csproj of App from App`s code

Tags: c#, uwp

Is there a way for reading a .csproj of a app from the same App`s code?
I did found questions related to the same, stating that Microsoft.Build APIs can be used. But those seem to be deprecated for UWP.
Also while reading it using XDocument, it is throwing an exception as InvalidOperation.
What extra step am I missing?

Comment: Why do you need it?

Comment: I want to check from code, if I can change a value of a string(say AppTitle) based on the ItemGroups in .csproj.

Answer (score 2):

No way to do it, the csproj is not copied to the app package when the app is built.

Comment: It seems there was a MSBuild API to do this, but it is not there for UWP.
See this : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649989/reading-a-csproj-file-in-c-sharp/4650212?noredirect=1#comment64810166_4650212]