# How to parse in a dotnet sdk csproj project file?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

I'm trying to load a csproj file using `Project` from `Microsoft.Build` package.

```
var projectFile = new Project("project.csproj");
```

This however results in the following exception:

> Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.InvalidProjectFileException: 'The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web' specified could not be found.

I want to be able to work on the project's properties, is it possible to get this working with dotnet sdk or should I just parse it as XML?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4650212/2981403 I guess this may be sufficient?

Comment: @Hozikimaru `Project.Load()`  from the `Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine` is still unhappy about the new csproj format, though in a different way:
`Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.InvalidProjectFileException: 'The default XML namespace of the project must be the MSBuild XML namespace.`