# Trying to deserialize a netcore csproj from XML to Object

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, deserialization

I'm trying to deserialise a xml doc into a poco class, obviously, the `csproj` files aren't the strictest XML files (missing `xml` header`), but they pass all the validation checks.

The error I'm getting is `<Project xmlns=''> was not expected.`, and the code to deserialise is below.

Have I missed something blindingly obvious?

`var csProj = projPath.ParsePathToXML<CsProj2.Models.Project>("Project");`

```
public static T ParsePathToXML<T>(this string @this, string root = "")
    {
        string xml = File.ReadAllText(@this);

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T), root);
        T result;

        using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
        {
            result = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }

        return result;
    }


[XmlRoot(ElementName = "PropertyGroup")]
public class PropertyGroup
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "TargetFramework")]
    public string TargetFramework { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "RuntimeIdentifier")]
    public string RuntimeIdentifier { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "RuntimeFrameworkVersion")]
    public string RuntimeFrameworkVersion { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput")]
    public string TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "PreserveCompilationContext")]
    public string PreserveCompilationContext { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "AssemblyName")]
    public string AssemblyName { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "OutputType")]
    public string OutputType { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "PackageId")]
    public string PackageId { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "GenerateAssemblyTitleAttribute")]
    public string GenerateAssemblyTitleAttribute { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "GenerateAssemblyDescriptionAttribute")]
    public string GenerateAssemblyDescriptionAttribute { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "GenerateAssemblyConfigurationAttribute")]
    public string GenerateAssemblyConfigurationAttribute { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "GenerateAssemblyCompanyAttribute")]
    public string GenerateAssemblyCompanyAttribute { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute")]
    public string GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "GenerateAssemblyCopyrightAttribute")]
    public string GenerateAssemblyCopyrightAttribute { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "GenerateAssemblyVersionAttribute")]
    public string GenerateAssemblyVersionAttribute { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "GenerateAssemblyFileVersionAttribute")]
    public string GenerateAssemblyFileVersionAttribute { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "DocumentationFile")]
    public string DocumentationFile { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Authors")]
    public string Authors { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest")]
    public string PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "VersionPrefix")]
    public string VersionPrefix { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "VersionSuffix")]
    public string VersionSuffix { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "IsPackable")]
    public string IsPackable { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Content")]
public class Content
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "CopyToOutputDirectory")]
    public string CopyToOutputDirectory { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Update")]
    public string Update { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "ItemGroup")]
public class ItemGroup
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Content")]
    public List<Content> Content { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "PackageReference")]
    public List<PackageReference> PackageReference { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ProjectReference")]
    public ProjectReference ProjectReference { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "BuildOutputInPackage")]
    public BuildOutputInPackage BuildOutputInPackage { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "PackageReference")]
public class PackageReference
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Include")]
    public string Include { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Version")]
    public string Version { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "ProjectReference")]
public class ProjectReference
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Include")]
    public string Include { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "PrivateAssets")]
    public string PrivateAssets { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "BuildOutputInPackage")]
public class BuildOutputInPackage
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Include")]
    public string Include { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Target")]
public class Target
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ItemGroup")]
    public ItemGroup ItemGroup { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "DependsOnTargets")]
    public string DependsOnTargets { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Project")]
public class Project
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "PropertyGroup")]
    public List<PropertyGroup> PropertyGroup { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ItemGroup")]
    public List<ItemGroup> ItemGroup { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Target")]
    public Target Target { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Sdk")]
    public string Sdk { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The xml is invalid if it doesn't have a value for the attribute.  Should be something like this : xmlns:p=''"

Comment: Ok - in that case it's invalid - any suggestions how to parse it?

Comment: You have to fix XML before parsing.

Comment: It's not my XML, it's the XML of a CSPROJ file.

Comment: the it is wrong.  Don't know how it was created.  Then just fix it.  the project is apparently is ignoring the error.

Comment: It can't be fixed, visual studio creates it. It's standard c# project.

Comment: I'll use this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649989/reading-a-csproj-file-in-c-sharp/4650212#4650212

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to specify your root element by using XmlRootAttribute.
Instead of ... new XmlSerializer(typeof(T), root)

```
new XmlSerializer(typeof(T), new XmlRootAttribute(root));
```